# Showing that the order of the group and all the element is the same.

Tags: field-theory, finite-fields

If $f=x^n-1 \in K[x]$, $L$ a splitting field of $f$ and $\gamma\in L$ the generator of $H= \{\alpha \in L \mid \alpha^n=1\} , m=|H|$, 
how can I show that $m|n$, should it depend on the characteristic of the field?? 
 And $$ \phi \in G=\operatorname{Aut}(L|K)$$

How can I show that there exists $ k\le m $ $\gcd (m,n)=1 $ and $\phi(\gamma)=\gamma^k$ and it gives a injective homomorphism to $\mathbb Z_m $ ?

Comment: Did you mean to write $\,H=\{\alpha\in L\;\;;\;\;\alpha^n=1\}\,\,,\,|H|=m\,$ ...or something close to this. Please do check that what you write comes out clearly *before* sending the question!

Comment: @DonAntonio : Yes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a subgroup of $L^\times$, $H$ is cyclic. Hence $\gamma^k=1$ iff $k$ is a multiple of $m$. Thus $f(\gamma)=0$ implies $m|n$.

For $\Phi\in G$, we must have $f(\Phi(\gamma))=\Phi(f(\gamma))=0$, hence $\Phi(\gamma)\in H$ and there exists $k\le m$ with $\Phi(\gamma)=\gamma^k$. Since $\Phi$ has some inverse $\Psi$, gow which by the same argument $\Psi(\gamma)=\gamma^r$ for some $r$, we have $\gamma=\Psi(\Phi(\gamma))=\gamma^{rk}$ and conclude that $rk\equiv 1\pmod m$, hence $\gcd(k,m)=1$ and we can view $k$ as an element of $(\mathbb Z/m \mathbb Z)^\times$. Since exponents multiply when composing such exponentiation maps, we see that $\Phi\mapsto k$ is in fact a homomorphism from $G$ to the multiplicative group  $(\mathbb Z/m \mathbb Z)^\times$. Since $L=K[\gamma]$, a $\Phi\in G$ with $\Phi(\gamma)=\gamma$ is the identity, hence the homomorphism is injective.

Comment: Thank you . What can i say about $n$ and $m$ if $m$ is prime ?